# using grepl is not achieve the result I want

Tags: r, grepl

```
x <- c('aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'bb', 'bc')

grep('a', x, value=TRUE) 
[1] "aa" "ab" "ac"
```

However, When I applied to my example, it is not working properly.

```
 > logit_coef$label
"(Intercept)"     "changer"  "changem"  "revenue"     
 "mou"     "overage"  "roam"   "conference"  "months" "uniqsubs" "custcare"
 "retcalls"  "dropvce"   "eqpdays"   "refurb|yes"  "smartphone|yes"  
 "highcreditr|yes"  "occupation|student"      "occupation|retired"


grep('|', logit_coef$label, value=TRUE)
```

It gives me all of the columns, I only want to name of columns contain '|'

```
 "smartphone|yes" "highcreditr|yes"  "occupation|student"      
 "occupation|retired"  That is the result I want
```

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible data set using `dput`. You can do `dput(taxi)` assuming the taxi data.frame is small.

Comment: And if the taxi data frame isn't small enough, do `dput(taxi[1:20, ])` to give us just the first 20 rows.

Comment: I did.  I put the data on the post.

Comment: Add `fixed = TRUE`

Comment: `|` is a special character in regex. You can either use the `fixed = TRUE` argument to skip fancy regex patterns and just do exact matching `grep('|', logit_coef$label, fixed = TRUE)`, or you can escape it with two backslashes, `grep('\\|', logit_coef$label, value = TRUE)`